# Unique Session for each browser tab .net core 3.1 Angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-3.1

In my application we are making dynamic connection strings which connects different Databases as per the URL and we are storing it in session for further post requests. The problem is when i simultaneously open another instance which connects another database and if i came back to first instance the last connected connectionstring remains.

For Example:

1. https://localhost:44360/apps/AAA -> connects AAA Database
2. https://localhost:44360/apps/BBB -> connects BBB Database

i am opening 1st url and in another tab opening 2nd one then again if i come back to 1 it points BBB database only. Because of session

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to use the session? We have a similar system, but we cache connection strings server side and use an `SqlConnectionFactory` (using Dapper) to generate our connections which takes into account tenancy.

Comment: Which Connecting string needs to be connected depends on the result of 1st api call of each URL and we are just replacing the specified database name from the result of 1st api call and making use of the new connection string for further calls.